# How can I make an import library in binary form that can be linked by VC/GCC?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, gcc, linker, dllimport

Firstly sorry for my poor English.

I'm now writing a tool to build import library of a dll in windows, it will output the binary form of obj files. then I can put them together by linker.
Currently it can generate OBJs with import descriptor, import lookup table, import thunk.
I nearly make it work but get stuck with some problem.

I researched the import library (.lib) files generated by VC and GCC, deciding to **imitate what GCC does**.
I found that it contains IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORs and IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32s just the same as what I saw in an EXE.

So I make my own one as it does, but the linker won't generate the EXE as I want.

I hope it links my lib in this order:

```
.idata$2 (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)
.idata$4 as FirstThunk
.idata$4 contains NullThunk
.idata$5 as OriginalFirstThunk
.idata$5 contains NullThunk
.idata$6 contains DLL's filename
```

I knew that the number after section name + $ can direct the linker to put the data in order, and that's NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR in .idata$3 does.

the problem is, **the linker strips the section which is not referred even if another section in the same obj is referred**. for example, I put NullThunk and DLL's name in a file called dllname, contains

```
section 1: .idata$4, 0x00000000
section 2: .idata$5, 0x00000000
section 3: .idata$6, a.dll\0
symbols: _DllName, external, sect3+0
```

the _DllName is referred by the import descriptor so it's linked, but .idata$4 and .idata$5 is stripped.
so the NullThunk is not linked, what I see in CFF Explorer is that the EXE which linker generated imports hundreds of symbols from my DLL.

The second question is, **how can I direct the linker to make sure that NullThunk is put after IAT?** because they are all in .idata$5.

And another problem, **when I try to make my lib contains 2 imported functions, the linker select only one of them, throw the other away.** In detail, I have 2 functions: int __stdcall add(int, int); and sub. In the linker's generated code, call to sub seems correct but call to add become "call [RVA:0] (ff 25 00400000)". What happened?

After a week's trial and error finally I gave up and turn to asking for help.

this is the file my tool generated(I packed them into a lib):
http://filebin.ca/19oJUzj8z1vN/add.lib

neither GCC nor VC generated correct EXE when link to this import library.

How can I solve these problems?

Regards,
LeiMing

Comment: Have you looked at what [LLVM's MC](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/MC/) does? It also generates object files like GCC.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

I just rename all members in generated archive (.lib file) to the same name,
and put the nullthunk object in the end of the archive (last member),
the 3 problems disappear.

I don't know the reason in details but it works.

Now my tool can generate import library successfully.

and other points that need to care about are the order of offsets, strings in first link member and second link member. Padding between archive members is also a point to care.